# Google Maps autocomplete only Streets with Number

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I have an website where i want to pinpoint user input to geocoords and using that adresse for something like a meeting.

The problem is that google autocomplete also shows "ZIP-Codes only" or Streets without a streetno.

Is there anyway to filter the autocomplete results before displaying them?

```
var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
            document.getElementById('pac-input'));
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(52.66805480068766, 13.7713623046875),
            new google.maps.LatLng(52.32191088594773, 12.98858642578125));
var autocomplete_options = {
        bounds: defaultBounds,
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'de'},
        types: ['geocode']
    };
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, autocomplete_options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', callServer);
```

My testsite to see the autocomplete can be found here: 
http://www.winterreifenwechsel.de/welcome/termine

Try some inputs like 14169  (zip code) or Wilskistr (for street without housenumber).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Place Types parameter in the URL request of the Autocomplete API which accepts only the locations with the geocode. This would enable the autocomplete results based on locations that have a proper lat lang and not a region.

Here is the API request for that:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types;=geocode&language;=fr&key;=API_KEY
```

For more details please refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types) Google's official doc.

**EDIT**

Then I would say use the Places Autocomplete address form in your webapp. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) for that which will restrict users to use address which you can pass as lat lng in your ,aps.

Comment: i already use  types: ['geocode'] but there are still autocompletes with only zipcodes.